# UITableViewCell added custom view loading issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hello I want to add custom cell seperator for my `UITableView`So in my `cllforRowAtIndex`delegate

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier]
}
```

after this I am adding custom `UIView` to my cell.content view

```
 UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.contentView.frame.size.height - 1.0, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, 1)];

    lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:61.0/255 green:80.0/255 blue:118.0/255 alpha:1.0];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lineView];
```

But my problem is when it loads first time my seperator right side is not going to the edg of the `UITableView` but once I scrolled the table it gose to the full width. why is that? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a custom `UITableViewCell`
2. Set the frame of the separator in `layoutSubviews` method of the cell

Or you can also change the separator color like this if this is the case:

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor myColor]];
```

Comment: or cant we change the default seperator color?

Comment: You could, it's easy `[self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor myColor]];`